# How to grant my second user permissions to read and write USB drives mounted by me via GUI (and vice versa)?

Tags: usb, permissions, mount

My user account is `renyhp`. I have created a new user, let's call it `seconduser`, with

```
sudo useradd --gid renyhp -G cdrom,dip,plugdev,sambashare --create-home seconduser
```

Since it has `plugdev`, it is able to mount and unmount USB drives seamlessly. However, if `renyhp` mounts (via GUI, ie by clicking on the USB icon in the dock or on the drive in nautilus) a USB drive, then I change accounts and go to `seconduser`, I can't read or write on the USB drive. The same happens if `seconduser` mounts a USB and `renyhp` tries to read or write.

I know that there are easy workarounds for this. I could mount the USB drive via command line and grant permissions, but I won't go every time to the command line for such a simple and intuitive task as accessing a USB stick. I could insert a line into `/etc/fstab`, but that requires to do it for every single USB stick that will be inserted.

So is there a way to change the default options of the `mount` call that is done by the GUI?